# How to override Adminhtml template files in Magento 2.3?

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, template

How to override Adminhtml template files in Magento 2.3? In a proper way.

File to override:

```
vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/templates/order/totals.phtml
```

Comment: Which template file do you want to override?

Comment: vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/templates/order/totals.phtml

Comment: Please check my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For overriding `vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/templates/order/totals.phtml` file you need to create a module.

Create sales_order_view.xml at

> app/code/Your_VendorName/Your_ModuleName/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_view.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="order_totals">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module::order/totals.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Then Copy totals.phtml file from

```
vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/templates/order/totals.phtml
```

To

```
app/code/Your_Vendor/Your_Module/view/adminhtml/templates/order/totals.phtml
```

**Hope it helps!!!**

Answer (score 1):

**First Step:**

Path of the XML OSCP/ModuleName/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="column_name">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" translate="true" xsi:type="string">OSCP_ModuleName::order/items/column/name.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Then copy the original file to

OSCP/ModuleName/view/adminhtml/templates/order/items/column/name.phtml

This is the Basic Pattern in Magento 2.3

Comment: i used this pattern but not working

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="column_name">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module::order/totals.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>

Comment: This is the Only way as Magento Said https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/templates/template-override.html

Comment: not getting any error changes not happened

Comment: okay just echo "test"; and exit();  on the file path: OSCP/ModuleName/view/adminhtml/templates/order/items/column/name.phtml. and Check whether Echo prints or not.

Comment: should i  need to create registration.php and composer.php

Comment: Yes you should. Basic Module Structure you need to create, with the help of this link: https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/

Comment: Alright i am doing

Comment: Thanks now its working