# How to override file dialog (files.phtml) from adminhtml?

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, overrides

Magento 2.4

I want to override `/vendor/magento/module-cms/view/adminhtml/templates/browser/content/files.phtml` but found no suitable way to do it. So, how can I override this adminhtml template? Do I need my own module? If so, what layout file do I need to achieve what I want?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried this solution ?
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/134897/how-to-override-a-template-file-in-module-creation-in-magento2

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/290075/how-to-override-adminhtml-template-files-in-magento-2-3

Comment: Yes, i need to know the specific xml file which I need in my case. The links only show how to do it for the order totals and the corresponding xml file.